# Do any Android phones support 256GB of storage?

Tags: sd-card, hardware, storage

I'd like a phone, preferably Android, with 256 GB of storage.

To the best of my knowledge, no 256 GB microSD cards exist (despite a few [scammy Amazon listings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017C8XH02)).  Therefore, the phone would either need to have (1) a fullsize SD slot or (2) dual microSD slots.  I don't know of any android phones that have a fullsize SD slot, although there are of course tablets that do.  And the only Android phone I know that promised dual microSD cards is the [vaporware Saygus V2](http://www.androidauthority.com/saygus-delays-what-is-going-on-650149/).

Do any solutions exist that don't involve solder or external devices?

Comment: In theory you could connect a Micro-USB stick to your phone that may have 256GB of storage, but you could easily use a *Micro-USB to USB cable* to connect larger storages (like HDD's up to 6TB), if you are able to supply the auxiliary power somehow.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm only interested in internal solutions. I'll update the question.

Comment: Just found out: Sandisk apparently sells 200 GB Micro-SD cards in their *SANDISK ULTRA* lineup, but remember that your phone has to support storage devices of that size (most of the current-gen phones are rated at 64 GB or 128 GB). Although I recommend buying multiple smaller cards, because together they will cost less than one big one.

Comment: Thanks! That is very close to what I need. (Multiple cards isn't preferred since I really don't like swapping.)

Comment: BTW, the consensus seems to be that SDXC cards over 64GB do work with phones like the Galaxy S4 under newer versions of Android, even if Samsung hasn't formally guaranteed support.

Comment: That's true, I know my Samsung Galaxy W was only rated 32 GB but worked with 64 GB. It's just not guaranteed. I'm sure the 200 GB card will work on most modern phones, but again those cards are cutting edge and I don't know if they are supported by your phone.

Comment: GiantTree, could you post your comment as an answer so that it can be up-voted and accepted?

Comment: Or you could use a HDD of 500GB or 1TB and connect it with you phone using OTG cable. It works fine in most of the phones supporting OTG([usb-on-the-go](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-on-the-go/info)).

Answer (score 1):

[A quick search on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=256GB+microSD) gave a bunch of results.

- SanDisk Ultra has a 256GB model (red and pale yellow)
- Samsung EVO+ has a 256GB model (red)
- Samsung EVO Select has a 256GB model (green)
- Other manufacturers also have 256 GB models, e.g. Patriot LX and ADATA Premier
- Lexar has 256GB models but I've heard they're ceasing producing storage products

Oh, there's one more thing that I'd like to note: The "maximum supported storage capacity" actually depends on the SoC (chip) and system. So as long as your phone is running on an SoC later than 2015 and Android 5+ (Lollipop) then it should have no problem supporting a 256GB microSD card.

Comment: Yep, 18 months makes a big difference :)

Answer (score -1):

Moto X Force is one phone that supports cards up to 2TB.

> **Expandable Memory**
>
> With the option to add up to 2 TB of additional storage space using a microSD card, the Moto X Force offers plenty of room to store your favourite pictures, videos, music and apps.

<sup>[Original screenshot of the device specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXpdz.png)</sup>

Though currently, I don't see cards with a capacity of more than 256GB.